# laravel send mail on server with gmail not working

Tags: php, email, laravel, swiftmailer

hi in my laravel application im sending mail when i create a new user !! so in localhost i use gmail smtp with my gmail account and username and it's working but on the server i got this error

```
Swift_TransportException
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not    accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 pn5sm18998642wjc.4 - gsmtp "
```

here is my code

```
if ($user->save())
        {   
             View::composer('emails.auth.userMail', function($view)
                {
                    $mail = Input::get('email');
                    $pass = Input::get('password');
                  $view->with('username' , $mail )->with('password' , $pass );
                });

            Mail::send('emails.auth.userMail', $data, function($message) use ($user)
                {
                    $message->to(Input::get('email'), '')
                    ->subject('Nouveau compte Happy Road ');


                });
```

in mail.php

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 465,
'from' => array('address' => name@gmail.com', 'name' => 'name'),
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'username' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
'password' => 'mypassword',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

Comment: what is your email configuration ? at config/mail.php

Comment: solved by genering a new password for the application https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

Comment: Add that as a answer so other users coming here in the future can quickly find the solution.

Answer (score 4):

solved by genering a new password for the application `security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords`

Comment: Hi,sorry I have a same problem,what do you mean generate a new password for the application??

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119004/how-to-setup-gmail-smtp-server-for-osx-mail-with-2-step-verification-and-app-spe

Comment: hi im using our own domain. but i also experiencing this problem:

Comment: this is my env file
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=user@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_FROM=user@mydomain.com
MAIL_NAME=No-reply
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem . To do this action you need to go to your

**gmail security section**

. Then you will change the **security permission** ***disabled*** to ***enable***. That's it.