# Not working email send in Laravel on live server

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-4

It is working on my localhost . But on live server not working.
It shows following error
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]
How to solve it?

And my app/config/mail.php

```
<?php

return array(

    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'from' => array('address' => 'myaddress', 'name' => 'Name'),
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

);
```

Comment: You might want to flesh out your questions a bit more otherwise you won't get an answer. For example, how are you sending mail (php mail or laravel Mail::send()?) and what is your app/config/mail.php settings?

Comment: What could be the problem is your Firewall blocking the IP. Try to Whitelist the SMTP IP. <br>
[Answer found here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-cimy-swift-smtp-connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtpgmailcom-connection-timed-o)

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://goo.gl/mFdE9M

Comment: Not sure if this is useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769615/laravel-send-mail-on-server-with-gmail-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
return array(

    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'from' => array('address' => 'myaddress', 'name' => 'Name'),
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

);
```

Hope this will work for both your local as well as live server.

Answer (score 0):

It will work in laravel 5.1 
In your .env file 
change the follwoing

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=www.yourhost.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your email address
MAIL_PASSWORD=email password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

change in config/mail.php

```
return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mail'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'www.yourhostname.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => 'youremail@domain.com', 'name' => 'any name'],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
];
```